# Getting Pandas to work

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas only works with my iPython notebooks, not when I try to use it on my computer in a regular script. When I try to import pandas, it says 'no module found.' I'm getting quite confused looking through directories trying to uninstall python and sort out the version differences. Could someone provide me a step-by-step how to get pandas to work with a script I'm writing in say, Sublime?

Comment: Grow bamboo. Feed bamboo. Repeat until pandas are fat and happy.

Comment: Chances are that IPython notebooks and "regular" python are different versions. So when you installed the notebooks and pandas, it was not in your "regular" python.

Comment: I hope you have not named your script `pandas.py` !!

Comment: Like Paul H says, it sounds like you have two different version of python installed. If you have linux or mac, write `which python` and `which ipython` on the terminal and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 0):

well if you can't get other help just install [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) (free) which has all you need for each platform, ready to go. your question, otherwise does not give anyone enough info to go with...